# Why do I have an "Impossible to get exclusive lock" error when upgrading?

Tags: upgrade

When I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10, just after the step called "Defining the new packages", the following message pops-up:

> Impossible to obtain an exclusive lock.
>   This usually means that another package management application (such as apt-get or aptitude) is already running. Please first close that other application.

What should I do?

---

Original untranslated version:

*Quand je veux upgrader Ubuntu 12.4 vers la version 12.10, après la "définition de nouveaux paquets" le message suivant s'affiche : «  IMPOSSIBLE D'OBTENIR UN VERROU EXCLUSIF. Ceci signifie généralement qu'une autre application de gestion de paquets (telle que apt-get ou aptitude) est déjà en cours d'exécution. Veuillez d'abord fermer cette application. » Je ne sais pas quoi faire. Merci de votre aide.*

Answer (score 1):

There is probably another app running on your system that is updating your software. This could be apt-get in a terminal, aptitude in a terminal, the Update Manager or even the Ubuntu Sofware Center. Close all of those and then try upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10 again.

If this doesn't work, the really fastest way to solve your problem is to log out and in again.

---

*Il y a probablement une autre application en train de faire des mises à jour. Cela peut être apt-get dans un terminal, aptitude dans un terminal, le Gestionnaire de Mises à Jour ou encore la Logithèque Ubuntu. Ferme les toutes puis réessaie de faire la mise à niveau vers Ubuntu 12.10.*

*Le moyen le plus brutal mais aussi le plus rapide est de fermer ta session puis de te reconnecter.*

Answer (score 0):

That means that another package management process or application like `synaptic` or `apt-get` is running. Close the application and try again. If that doesn't work or you don't see any related process or application, try rebooting or in other cases this error appers when user try to run command with no admin previleges type `sudo` before command.